# iPhone : copyWithZone : releasing an object before its return?

Tags: iphone, release, return, retain, copywithzone

I read in the apple documentation about copyWithZone : "The returned object is implicitly retained by the sender, who is responsible for releasing it". 
But... How may I release something I return... I'm going crazy !

Sample of code :

```
    - (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
        MyObject* obj = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] init]; // explicit retain
        [obj fillTheObj];

        return obj; // implicit retain
    }
```

Where should be the told release ?
I retain twice ? Uhhh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *sender* is responsible for releasing.  That means whoever calls your copy method takes ownership, i.e.:

```
MyObject *obj = ...
MyObject *aCopy = [obj copy];
... do stuff with aCopy
[aCopy release];
```

Comment: Okkkk, the sender of the call, not the sender of the object. That's more clear. But I'm really going crazy. So... I can pass myObject.var = [localvar copy] with a property in myObject defined as retain, and released in the dealloc. That would work fine, isn't it ?

Comment: @Oliver -- you'll be over-retaining if you did that.  If the `var` property is declared as `retain`, then the correct assignment would be `myObject.var = [[localvar copy] autorelease]`.  But it sounds like what you really want is to declare the property as `copy`, then you can simply do `myObject.var = localvar`.